# Access Next Element within a foreach loop

Tags: c#

```
int i = 0;    
foreach (var logInAlarm in logInAlarms)
 {
//Custom Code
//For comparison reason i need to access the next logInAlarm in the list.
 var nextDate = logInAlarms[i + 1].Date;
i++;
}
```

I came up with an idea to add a counter variable and later access the element using that counter. Is this the best way?

Comment: You've just reinvented the for loop - What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Soory i have updated the code.

Comment: Why can't you use a for loop as Sayse said?

Comment: There is no need of `i`. try with `logInAlarms.Date`

Answer (score 4):

You are better using the existing for loop which can stop an out of bounds error, but your approach is more or less correct

```
for(int i = 0; i < logInAlarms.Length - 1; i++)
    var nextDate = logInAlarms[i+1].Date;
```

---

Test code for the end of array

```
    var arr = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).ToArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
        Console.Write(arr[i]);

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `i < logInAlarms.Length - 2`?

Comment: No, but it should handle the last iteration, as when it comes to `i= logInAlarms.Length - 1` then `logInAlarms[i+1].Date` would fail.

Comment: If you have it with -2 then you will not handle the last index. What if OP wants to check current index date with next index date?

Comment: He stated `For comparison reason i need to access the next logInAlarm in the list`, so he might need to compare each date with the next in the sequence.

Comment: @GiannisParaskevopoulos - Thanks, I've added test code that proves the required end (I'm easily convinced first thing in the morning apparently)

Answer (score 3):

Because you're dealing with a collection that has an indexer property accepting an integer (for instance an array or `List<T>`), you should use a `for` loop.

```
for (int v = 1; v < logInAlarms.Length; v++)
{
    var current = logInAlarms[v - 1];
    var next = logInAlarms[v];

    // use current and next
}
```

However, if you weren't dealing with an array or `List<T>` and were instead using any sort of `IEnumerable` as the `foreach` loop supports, I would use this more generalized code.

```
var enumerator = logInAlarms.GetEnumerator();

if(enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    var current = enumerator.Current;

    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        var next = enumerator.Current;

        // use current and next

        current = next;
    }

    // current is now the last node, to which there is no "next." Deal with that or ignore it as you see so fit.
}
```

I suggest this, again, only because it will work any time that a `foreach` does, whereas a `for` loop will only work in certain instances (`ElementAt` notwithstanding). If you can use a `for`, do, but if you can't, this will work.

Just for fun, you could even write a helper function. You'd need to use `Enumerable.Cast<T>` if your original type implemented `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<T>`, but this would still be pretty useful if you do a lot like this. I've also implemented a `using` block as suggested by @JeppeStigNielsen in a comment here, you may or may not want to do that in the first example, depending on whether your implementation implements `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `IEnumerable` (which is being phased out anyway, and is barely used).

```
public IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> GetPairs<T>(IEnumerable<T> coll)
{
    using (var enumerator = logInAlarms.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if(enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            var current = enumerator.Current;

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                var next = enumerator.Current;

                yield return new Tuple<T, T>(current, next);

                current = next;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask what about this is downvote worthy? I recognize that people would rather him use a `for` loop, and I addressed that rather fully in my post, but I don't see why a more generalized example that supports the full is harmful to anyone, particularly since use of `IEnumerable<T>` is generally better practice than many alternate solutions.

Comment: Yeah, agreed. I have countered.

Comment: I like it. If `logInAlarms` implements the generic `IEnumerable<>`, one could consider writing `using (var enumerator = logInAlarms.GetEnumerator()) { ... }` since some implementation might actually demand `Dispose` finally.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen great point. I always forget that `IEnumerator<T>` implements that. I've edited my question to reflect that.